# Getting "Access from host not allowed, or unknown host" from Torque PBS Server using qstat command

Tags: pbs, torque

I'm trying to run command `qstat` but instead of getting the queue status I'm seeing this error:

> Cannot resolve default server host 'torqueserver' - check server_name
>   file. qstat: cannot connect to server torqueserver (errno=15010)
>   Access from host not allowed, or unknown host

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is 'torqueserver' the hostname of the node running pbs_server? In the server_name file located in /server_name (default for  is /var/spool/torque) the actual hostname of the node running pbs_server should be in that file.

Comment: I changed it to my virtual box machine name and it worker (showed nothing because there is no queue).

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have looked at /var/spool/torque/server_name and the name is torqueserver.

What other diagnostic steps would you take?

Comment: @Omroth change it to the hostname of the server where Torque is running.

Comment: and what is the host name of the local server?